# scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh() doesn't give out the same result as Matlab's eigs(), why?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I'm using `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh()` to solve the generalized eigenvalue problem. I wanna use `eigsh()` because I'm manipulating some large sparse matrix. The problem is I cannot get the right answers and the eigenvalues and eigenvectors output from `eigsh()` are totally different from what I've got from Matlab's `eigs()`.

It looks like this:
data:

```
a: 
   304.7179  103.1667   36.9583   61.3478   11.5724
    35.5242  111.4789   -9.8928    8.2586   -4.7405
    10.8358    4.3433  145.6586   26.5153   13.1871
    -1.1924   -2.5430    0.4322   43.1886   -0.6098
   -18.7751   -8.8031   -4.3962   -5.8791   17.6588
b: 
   736.9822  615.7946  587.6828  595.7169  545.1878
   615.7946  678.2142  575.7579  587.3469  524.7201
   587.6828  575.7579  698.6223  593.5402  534.3675
   595.7169  587.3469  593.5402  646.0410  530.1114
   545.1878  524.7201  534.3675  530.1114  590.1373
```

in python:
a,b are numpy.ndarray

```
In [11]: import scipy.sparse.linalg as lg

In [14]: x,y=lg.eigsh(a,M=b,k=2,which='SM')

In [15]: x
Out[15]: array([ 0.01456738,  0.22578463])

In [16]: y
Out[16]: 
array([[ 0.00052614,  0.00807034],
       [ 0.00514091, -0.01593113],
       [ 0.00233622, -0.00429671],
       [ 0.01877451, -0.06259276],
       [ 0.01491696,  0.08002341]])

In [18]: a.dot(y[:,0])-x[0]*b.dot(y[:,0])
Out[18]: array([ 1.74827445,  0.30325634,  0.71299604,  0.42842245, -0.24724681])

In [19]: a.dot(y[:,1])-x[1]*b.dot(y[:,1])
Out[19]: array([-2.2463206 , -1.64704567, -0.80086734, -1.56796329, 0.03027861])
```

It could be seen that the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are not good enough to recomposing the original matrix.

However, in MATLAB it works well:

```
[y,x] = eigs(a,b,2,'sm');

y =

    0.0037   -0.0141
   -0.0056    0.0151
    0.0015    0.0079
   -0.0117    0.0666
   -0.0298   -0.0753
x =

    0.0202         0
         0    0.3499
a*x(:,1)-y(1,1)*b*x(:,1)

ans =

   1.0e-14 *

   -0.3775
    0.0777
    0.0777
    0.0555
    0.0666
```

Plus, data b is positive definite:

```
In [24]: np.linalg.eigvals(b)
Out[24]: 
array([ 2951.07297125,   137.81545217,    90.40223937,   107.04818229,
          63.65818086])
```

Anybody could explain why I cannot get the right answer in python?

---

Using `lg.eigs()`we do get the same outputs as in MATLAB.
But...problem occurs when matrix becomes large like this:

[test_eigs.mat](https://github.com/woodywff/test_eigs.git)

in MATLAB we've got things like this:

```
>> [x,y] = eigs(A,B,4,'sm');
y =

0.0001         0         0         0
     0    0.0543         0         0
     0         0    0.1177         0
     0         0         0    0.1350
```

while in python(python3.5.2,scipy1.0.0) using `lg.eigs(A,M=B,k=4,which='SM')` it results in eigenvalues as:

```
array([  4.43277284e+51 +0.00000000e+00j,
     1.04797857e+48 +8.30096152e+47j,
     1.04797857e+48 -8.30096152e+47j,  -1.45582240e+31 +0.00000000e+00j])
```

Comment: Maybe because of the surplus `h`? I didn't look too deep into it but `eigsh` requires `A` to be symmetric or Hermitian, which your `A` is not. But `scipy` too has `eigs` which appears to be the same without that requirement.

Comment: Furthermore, the output of `eigsh()` and `eigs()` are randomly changing everytime. That's unacceptable in my program.

Comment: B is numerically positive semi-definite so you need `sigma` set.

Comment: Randomness is due to the starting vector v0 being random; you can provide some value for it to have non-random result (see the documentation of eigs). I haven't tried your large matrix yet.

Comment: @percusse I've tried `sigma`. Perhaps I don't get it much clear but I guess `sigma` needs to be fixed to a given value each round in my iteration, doesn't it? If that is the case, how come to get the anticipated value each time? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paul Panzer said, "h" in "eigsh" stands for [Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix), which your matrix A is not. (Also, having positive eigenvalues does not imply being positive definite; this is only true if the matrix is Hermitian to begin with.) The method `eigsh` does not check the input for being Hermitian; it just follows a process assuming it is; so the output is incorrect when the assumption fails.

Using eigs method produces the same results as Matlab:

```
x, y = lg.eigs(a,M=b,k=2,which='SM') 
np.real(x), np.real(y)  # x and y have tiny imaginary parts due to float math errors

(array([ 0.02022333,  0.34993346]), 
 array([[-0.00368007, -0.0140898 ],
    [ 0.0056435 ,  0.01509067],
    [-0.00154725,  0.00790518],
    [ 0.01170563,  0.06664118],
    [ 0.02981777, -0.07528778]]))
```

Of course, `eigs` takes a lot longer to run than `eigsh`.

---

Your second example is a 34 by 34 **dense** matrix, it has no zeros at all. Using sparse linear algebra on it is not reasonable; and there is a warning saying that the method did not converge. The regular linear algebra module works fine.

```
import scipy.linalg as la
sorted_eigenvals = np.sort(np.real(la.eigvals(Am, Bm)))
```

This returns

> 5.90947734e-05,   5.42521180e-02,   1.17669899e-01,        1.34952286e-01, ...

in agreement with MATLAB's output that you quoted (except Matlab rounds the numbers)

> 0.0001,   0.0543,  0.1177, 0.1350

Comment: Thanks a lot:) But... for larger matrix(in my scenario it ranges from 34*34 to 1000*1000) there are problems again. I've modified the question and uploaded the raw data files onto github. It would be so appreciated if you have any chance to have a check on it. Many thanks to you:)

Comment: I finally had time to test your matrix (tip: if you want someone to test your data in Python, don't present it in a format that only Matlab can read. You could have saved it as CSV with `csvwrite`). See the addition to the answer.